# passing multiline string parameter in powershell using jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I am trying to run a powershell script through jenkins.But facing issue in passing multiline string.

```
$content = @"
test1
test2
test3
"@
Add-content filepath $content
```

The above script which is running through jenkins but the content is getting save in one line.for example

```
test1test2test3
```

But i want to save it in below manner-

```
test1
test2
test3
```

Any solution how can i get the content save in different lines as mention above.

Comment: This seems like an encoding issue of the target file...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand your question correctly but hope this helps...

input (as array)=

```
$content = @("test1","test2","test3")
$content
```

output=

```
test1
test2
test3

Finished: SUCCESS
```

or you could use (if you are using multi-line string parameter):

```
$content =$content |foreach-object {$_.split(' ')}
```

which would split the variable into lines